# Bazel - unable to build with Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, bazel

First, I installed and configured Bazel, now I am able to succesfully compile and deploy app, using that [tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/android-app.html).

However, I'm stuck with Android Studio. I installed official Bazel plugin, then tried to import my Bazel project to Android studio (import from BUILD file). And I'm getting sync errors:

> Syncing project: Sync (incremental)... Updating VCS... Running Bazel
>   info... Command: bazel info --tool_tag=ijwb:AndroidStudio --curses=no
>   --color=yes --progress_in_terminal_title=no --
>
> Computing VCS working set... Querying targets in project
>   directories... Command: bazel query --tool_tag=ijwb:AndroidStudio
>   --output=label_kind --keep_going "attr(\"tags\", \"^((?!manual).)*$\", //src/main/...:all)" --
>
> 2 targets found under project directories; syncing 2 of them. Sync
>   targets from project view directories:
>   //src/main/java/com/example/bazel:greeter_activity   //src/main:app
>
> Building Bazel targets... Command: bazel build
>   --tool_tag=ijwb:AndroidStudio --keep_going --build_event_binary_file=/tmp/intellij-bep-782d8b0b-2f34-43f6-8f09-1efdd034cbfb
>   --nobuild_event_binary_file_path_conversion --curses=no --color=yes --progress_in_terminal_title=no --aspects=@intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect
>   --override_repository=intellij_aspect=/home/michal/.AndroidStudio3.5/config/plugins/aswb/aspect
>   --output_groups=intellij-info-android,intellij-info-generic,intellij-info-java,intellij-resolve-android,intellij-resolve-java
>   -- //src/main/java/com/example/bazel:greeter_activity //src/main:app
>
> Loading:  Loading: 0 packages loaded Analyzing: 2 targets (0 packages
>   loaded, 0 targets configured) Analyzing: 2 targets (31 packages
>   loaded, 622 targets configured) ERROR:
>   /home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/bazel/2/examples-master/android/tutorial/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/BUILD:5:1:
>   in @intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect
>   aspect on android_library rule
>   //src/main/java/com/example/bazel:greeter_activity:  Traceback (most
>   recent call last):    File
>   "/home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/bazel/2/examples-master/android/tutorial/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/BUILD",
>   line 5
>         @intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect(...)
>     File
>   "/home/michal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_michal/d2759e71c9e0462cf95e741761af2e78/external/intellij_aspect/intellij_info_bundled.bzl",
>   line 54, in _aspect_impl      intellij_info_aspect_impl(target, ctx,
>   semantics)    File
>   "/home/michal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_michal/d2759e71c9e0462cf95e741761af2e78/external/intellij_aspect/intellij_info_impl.bzl",
>   line 895, in intellij_info_aspect_impl        collect_android_info(target,
>   ctx, semantics, ide_info, <2 more arguments>)     File
>   "/home/michal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_michal/d2759e71c9e0462cf95e741761af2e78/external/intellij_aspect/intellij_info_impl.bzl",
>   line 706, in collect_android_info
>         get_res_artifacts(ctx.rule.attr.resource_files, andr...)    File
>   "/home/michal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_michal/d2759e71c9e0462cf95e741761af2e78/external/intellij_aspect/intellij_info_impl.bzl",
>   line 118, in get_res_artifacts        for file in resource.files: ... type
>   'depset' is not iterable. Use the `to_list()` method to get a list.
>   Use --incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false to temporarily disable
>   this check. INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (33 packages loaded, 699 targets
>   configured). INFO: Found 2 targets... INFO: Deleting stale sandbox
>   base
>   /home/michal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_michal/d2759e71c9e0462cf95e741761af2e78/sandbox
>   [0 / 1] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt ERROR:
>   command succeeded, but not all targets were analyzed INFO: Elapsed
>   time: 3.012s, Critical Path: 0.02s INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build
>   did NOT complete successfully FAILED: Build did NOT complete
>   successfully INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully build invocation result:
>   build_error Sync was successful, but there were Bazel build errors.
>   The project may not be fully updated or resolve until fixed. If the
>   errors are from your working set, please uncheck 'Bazel > Sync >
>   Expand Sync to Working Set' and try again. Parsing build outputs...
>   Total rules: 0, new/changed: 0, removed: 0 Reading IDE info result...
>   Updating target map Loaded 0 aspect files, total size 0kB Target map
>   size: 0 Reading jdeps files... Loaded 0 jdeps files, total size 0kB
>   Reading package manifests... Java content entry count: 1 Updating
>   Unpacked AAR libraries... Updating Jar Cache... Prefetching files...
>   Refreshing files Computing directory structure... Committing project
>   structure... Workspace has 0 libraries Android resource module count:
>   0, run config modules: 0, order entries: 0, generated resources: 0
>   Workspace has 2 modules Updating in-memory state... Could not read
>   from manifest file:
>   /home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/bazel/2/examples-master/android/tutorial/AndroidManifest.xml
>   Sync finished
>
> Error:(5, 1) in
>   @intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect
>   aspect on android_library rule
>   //src/main/java/com/example/bazel:greeter_activity:

Answer (score 0):

The pile of error messages here is hard to read, but here's the root cause:

> "/home/michal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_michal/d2759e71c9e0462cf95e741761af2e78/external/intellij_aspect/intellij_info_impl.bzl", line 118, in get_res_artifacts for file in resource.files: ... type 'depset' is not iterable. Use the to_list() method to get a list. Use --incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false to temporarily disable this check.

Either add `build --incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false` to your project's `.bazelrc` file, or wait for the next plugin release `v2019.09.16` that contains [the patch fix.](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/commit/ad367ad80a0f75797268ea1b0f8a115b2e7cba2a)

Comment: Where is `.bazelrc` located?

Comment: It should be located at your project's root directory. If it doesn't exist, you can create one.

Comment: @Jin I get `ERROR: Unrecognized option: --incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false`. What am I missing ?

Comment: What version of bazel is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to clean by `bazel clean --expunge`. It will remove all downloaded artifacts. You should clean and rebuild by below steps.
```

1. Please uncheck 'Bazel > Sync > Expand Sync to Working Set' and try again.
2. Build through bazel plugin from intellij